# How to make beamer block without block body

Tags: beamer

I know it's weird. But i'd like to put block title only before another block. Whenever i input

```
\begin{block}{Title}
\end{block}
```

without the content inside, the block body is still included. How to remove the block body, so that i'll have the block title only?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue!80!black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=blue!10!white}
    \onslide<+->{\begin{exampleblock}{BLA BLA}
    \end{exampleblock}}
    \onslide<+->{\begin{exampleblock}{BLA BLA}
            \begin{itemize}
                \justifying
                \item <3-> {BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }
                \item <4-> {BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA BLA }
            \end{itemize}
    \end{exampleblock}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "block title only before another block". Could you show us some scheme of the desired result ?

Comment: @BambOo please see my edit

Comment: @BambOo i mean, a block has 2 parts. Block title (to write a title) and block body (to write a content). I want to remove the block body.

Comment: Ok, now the question is what do you want to achieve : a two-line block title, a colored line above a block but with as vertical separation, something else ?

Comment: Maybe you can make a mock-up screenshot with cut and paste in MS Paint or similar to show what the desired output looks like?

Comment: @BambOo The second one. A colored line (block title) above the block (full block).

Comment: I guess campa answered !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just use a `beamercolorbox` and use the colour `block title example`. I've removed some stuff irrelevant to the question (the overlay specifications, the `itemize` & so on).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetheme{Copenhagen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Tinjauan Pustaka}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=blue!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body example}{use=structure,fg=black,bg=blue!10!white}

\begin{beamercolorbox}[rounded=true]{block title example}
BLA BLA BLA
\end{beamercolorbox}

\begin{exampleblock}{BLA BLA}
As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
used as a canon for our understanding.
\end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]